# Algorithm to divide region such that sum of distance is minimized

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, cluster-analysis, mathematical-optimization

Suppose we have `n` points in a bounded region of the plane. The problem is to divide it in 4 regions **(with a horizontal and a vertical line)** such that the sum of *a metric* in each region is minimized.

The *metric* can be for example, the sum of the distances between the points in each region ; or any other measure about the spreadness of the points. See the figure below.

[image: Example of a division]

I don't know if any clustering algorithm might help me tackle this problem, or if for instance it can be formulated as a simple optimization problem. Where the decision variables are the "*axes*".

Comment: Definitely look like an optimization problem and luckily it even looks like a convex minimization which should help most algorithms.

Comment: @JosepValls Yes, but I am having problems formulating it as one.

Comment: Is the metric of a region such that you know whether enlarging or shrinking a region will be an improvement?

Answer (score 2):

Note - probably incorrect. I will try and add another answer

The one dimensional version of minimising sums of squares of differences is convex. If you start with the line at the far left and move it to the right, each point crossed by the line stops accumulating differences with the points to its right and starts accumulating differences to the points to its left. As you follow this the differences to the left increase and the differences to the right decrease, so you get a monotonic decrease, possibly a single point that can be on either side of the line, and then a monotonic increase.

I believe that the one dimensional problem of clustering points on a line is convex, but I no longer believe that the problem of drawing a single vertical line in the best position is convex. I worry about sets of points that vary in y co-ordinate so that the left hand points are mostly high up, the right hand points are mostly low down, and the intermediate points alternate between high up and low down. If this is not convex, the part of the answer that tries to extend to two dimensions fails.

So for the one dimensional version of the problem you can pick any point and work out in time O(n) whether that point should be to the left or right of the best dividing line. So by binary chop you can find the best line in time O(n log n).

I don't know whether the two dimensional version is convex or not but you can try all possible positions for the horizontal line and, for each position, solve for the position of the vertical line using a similar approach as for the one dimensional problem (now you have the sum of two convex functions to worry about, but this is still convex, so that's OK). Therefore you solve at most O(n) one-dimensional problems, giving cost O(n^2 log n).

If the points aren't very strangely distributed, I would expect that you could save a lot of time by using the solution of the one dimensional problem at the previous iteration as a first estimate of the position of solution for the next iteration. Given a starting point x, you find out if this is to the left or right of the solution. If it is to the left of the solution, go 1, 2, 4, 8... steps away to find a point to the right of the solution and then run binary chop. Hopefully this two-stage chop is faster than starting a binary chop of the whole array from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be formulated as a MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) problem.

Lets introduce 4 quadrants A,B,C,D. A is right,upper, B is right,lower, etc. Then define a binary variable

```
 delta(i,k) = 1 if point i is in quadrant k
              0 otherwise
```

and continuous variables

```
 Lx, Ly : coordinates of the lines
```

Obviously we have:

```
sum(k, delta(i,k)) = 1
xlo <= Lx <= xup
ylo <= Ly <= yup
```

where `xlo,xup` are the minimum and maximum x-coordinate. Next we need to implement implications like:

```
delta(i,'A') = 1 ==>  x(i)>=Lx and y(i)>=Ly
delta(i,'B') = 1 ==>  x(i)>=Lx and y(i)<=Ly
delta(i,'C') = 1 ==>  x(i)<=Lx and y(i)<=Ly
delta(i,'D') = 1 ==>  x(i)<=Lx and y(i)>=Ly
```

These can be handled by so-called indicator constraints or written as linear inequalities, e.g.

```
x(i) <= Lx + (delta(i,'A')+delta(i,'B'))*(xup-xlo)
```

Similar for the others. Finally the objective is

```
min sum((i,j,k), delta(i,k)*delta(j,k)*d(i,j))
```

where `d(i,j)` is the distance between points i and j. This objective can be linearized as well.

After applying a few tricks, I could prove global optimality for 100 random points in about 40 seconds using Cplex. This approach is not really suited for large datasets (the computation time quickly increases when the number of points becomes large).

I suspect this cannot be shoe-horned into a convex problem. Also I am not sure this objective is really what you want. It will try to make all clusters about the same size (adding a point to a large cluster introduces lots of distances to be added to the objective; adding a point to a small cluster is cheap). May be an average distance for each cluster is a better measure (but that makes the linearization more difficult).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another attempt. Lay out a grid so that, except in the case of ties, each point is the only point in its column and the only point in its row. Assuming no ties in any direction, this grid has N rows, N columns, and N^2 cells. If there are ties the grid is smaller, which makes life easier.

Separating the cells with a horizontal and vertical line is pretty much picking out a cell of the grid and saying that cell is the cell just above and just to the right of where the lines cross, so there are roughly O(N^2) possible such divisions, and we can calculate the metric for each such division. I claim that when the metric is the sum of the squares of distances between points in a cluster the cost of this is pretty much a constant factor in an O(N^2) problem, so the whole cost of checking every possibility is O(N^2).

The metric within a rectangle formed by the dividing lines is SUM_i,j[ (X_i - X_j)^2 + (Y_i-Y_j)^2]. We can calculate the X contributions and the Y contributions separately. If you do some algebra (which is easier if you first subtract a constant so that everything sums to zero) you will find that the metric contribution from a co-ordinate is linear in the variance of that co-ordinate. So we want to calculate the variances of the X and Y co-ordinates within the rectangles formed by each division. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_formula_for_the_variance gives us an identity which tells us that we can work out the variance given SUM_i Xi and SUM_i Xi^2 for each rectangle (and the corresponding information for the y co-ordinate). This calculation can be inaccurate due to floating point rounding error, but I am going to ignore that here.

Given a value associated with each cell of a grid, we want to make it easy to work out the sum of those values within rectangles. We can create partial sums along each row, transforming 0 1 2 3 4 5 into 0 1 3 6 10 15, so that each cell in a row contains the sum of all the cells to its left and itself. If we take these values and do partial sums up each column, we have just worked out, for each cell, the sum of the rectangle whose top right corner lies in that cell and which extends to the bottom and left sides of the grid. These calculated values at the far right column give us the sum for all the cells on the same level as that cell and below it. If we subtract off the rectangles we know how to calculate we can find the value of a rectangle which lies at the right hand side of the grid and the bottom of the grid. Similar subtractions allow us to work out first the value of the rectangles to the left and right of any vertical line we choose, and then to complete our set of four rectangles formed by two lines crossing by any cell in the grid. The expensive part of this is working out the partial sums, but we only have to do that once, and it costs only O(N^2). The subtractions and lookups used to work out any particular metric have only a constant cost. We have to do one for each of O(N^2) cells, but that is still only O(N^2).

(So we can find the best clustering in O(N^2) time by working out the metrics associated with all possible clusterings in O(N^2) time and choosing the best).